# grouping / formatting `group` with `tags` with mysql or php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, formatting

lets say we have an array like this

from a mysql function like

```
function getGroups($limit = 10) {
    $data = $this->fetchAll ( 'SELECT gid, `group`, information, tag FROM groups 
    GROUP BY tag LIMIT ' . $limit );
    return $data;
}
```

Resulting

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'gid' => string '6' (length=1)
      'group' => string 'Media' (length=5)
      'tag' => string 'advertising' (length=11)
  1 => 
    array
      'gid' => string '8' (length=1)
      'group' => string 'Fashion' (length=10)
      'tag' => string 'shorts' (length=7)
  2 => 
    array
      'gid' => string '7' (length=1)
      'group' => string 'Automotive' (length=8)
      'tag' => string 'cars' (length=5)
  3 => 
    array
      'gid' => string '1' (length=1)
      'group' => string 'Fashion' (length=7)
      'tag' => string 'tshirt' (length=6)
```

i need to display somehow to this ( something like )

```
array
   0 =>
     array
       'group' => string 'Media'
       'tags' 
          array 
          0 => string 'advertising'

   1 =>
     array
       'group' => string 'Fashion'
       'tags'
          array 
          0 => string 'short'
          1 => string 'tshirt'   
   2 =>
     array
       'group' => string 'Automotive'
       'tags'
          array
          0 => 'cars'
```

simpler

```
group      tag
media      advertising
fashion    short
fashion    tshirt
automotive cars
```

to

```
media
  advertising
fashion
  short
  tshirt
automotive
  cars
```

**what is the best way to do this? from php array? or from the mysql ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to get a list of groups, plus all the tags for each group? `GROUP_CONCAT()` is the right way to get the tag list but you want to be grouping by `group`, not by `tag`:

```
function getGroups($limit = 10) {
    $data = (array) $this->fetchAll (
        'SELECT `group`,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `tag` ORDER BY `tag`) AS `tags`
        FROM `groups`
        GROUP BY `group` LIMIT ' . $limit
    );
    foreach ($data as $i => $row) {
        $data[$i]['tags'] = explode(',', $row['tags']);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function getGroups($limit = 10) {
    $data = $this->fetchAll ( 'SELECT gid, `group`, information, tag FROM groups 
    GROUP BY group LIMIT ' . $limit );
    return $data;
}
```

This will group you data with group, or you can use group_concat but then you will get `short, tshirt` something like this.

Comment: i assume it will be like fashion short. no tshirt in it. because it gets one tag ( grouping by group ). well maybe im wrong.

Comment: Yes sorry im wrong the group_concat is the solution, my mistake

Comment: @skowron-line im not sure how to use group_concat. any example ?

Comment: `'SELECT gid, GROUP_CONCAT(group), information, tag FROM groups  GROUP BY tag ` something like this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: `$data = $this->fetchAll ( 'SELECT gid, `group`, GROUP_CONCAT(`tag`) AS tags, information, tag FROM groups 
  GROUP BY `group` ORDER BY `group`, tag LIMIT ' . $limit );` ah i got the point,  'tags' => string 'tshirt,shorts' (length=15) but its , not arrays. anyway really helpful!. thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

I would add

ORDER BY group,tag

so the result set has all rows of the same group together.

Starting a new can then be done in php by comparing to the previous group and close/starting the new group when it has changed.

actually using hashes makes more sense...

```
$names = array();
$query = ''SELECT gid, `group`, information, tag FROM groups GROUP BY tag LIMIT ' . $limit'; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_rows) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($names[$row['group']], $row['tag']);
    }
}
```

Comment: how can we compare and close or start? can you give me an example? anyway thanks!